# Vue-Resource Authorization header unable to set

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, vue-router, vue-resource, laravel-passport

Unable to set authorization header to "Bearer (token)" in main.js file after Sign In, shows 401 unauthorized but the headers are set after refresh while accessing files list from server

*Detailed Description:*

**Specs:**

1. Vue @ 2.2.1
2. Vue Resource @ 1.3.4
3. Vue Router @ 2.6.0
4. Laravel @ 5.4
5. Laravel Passport @ 2.0

**Details:**

I use "Sign In" module to sign in and store access and refresh tokens and expiration in local storage using an Auth package as follows -

[image: Auth Package code (setters and getters for token)]

[ **Image Desc:** Auth Package code (setters and getters for token) ]

[image: Sign in module snippet to set token on arrival -- **Works correctly**]

[ **Image desc:** Sign in module snippet to set token on arrival -- **Works correctly**  ]

As shown above, the route goes to 'dash', which loads files module but fails to fetch data from https://localhost:8000/api/files

[image: unauthorized without refresh]

[ **Image desc:** unauthorized without refresh ]
[[image: without refresh, Vue.http.headers.common['Authorization'] shows "Bearer null"][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQhhg.png)

[ **Image desc:** without refresh, Vue.http.headers.common['Authorization'] shows "Bearer null" ]

But passes the token **after refreshing the page**...!

[image: after refresh, the token is passed successfully]
[ **Imag desc:** after refresh, the token is passed successfully ]

> And keeps on working until I don't refresh on sign in page after signing out and sign in again.

Any solutions will be appreciated.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: I found the solution..check my answer

Answer (score 3):

You need to intercept each `http` request and add the `Authorization` header to the request in the `main.js` file, for example

```
Vue.http.interceptors.push((request, next) => {
  request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + Vue.auth.getAccessToken())
  next()
})
```

Comment: This works as I mentioned in the question. But only **after refresh**

Answer (score 0):

Set your header common after you set your token and expiration, this allows you to set your header upon login.

```
setToken(){
  localStorage.setItem('token', token)
  localStorage.setItem('expiration', expiration)
  Vue.http.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + this.getToken();
}
```

Comment: I dumped the value of Vue.http.headers.common['Authoriztion'] before refresh, and it was not null. But the value was not sent with request